# Is 29 volts too much for a 24 volt thermostat?

Tags: thermostat, boiler

I replaced a digital non-programmable thermostat with a programmable thermostat and the new thermostat keeps the house around 60-62 no matter what temperature I set.

When I contacted the manufacturer, he had us test the voltage and indicated our 29 volts was too much for 24 volt thermostat.  Recommended getting a contractor out to resolve that - easier said than done.

Are there other programmable thermostats that have a more flexible range?

I haven't seen this range on packaging/specifications I'm looking at.  This is for a combiboiler if that makes a difference.

Picture of wiring:

[image]

Thermostat: Honeywell RTH2510, Boiler: Vesta VRC

Comment: That's not that weird.  AC voltage is listed in RMS (a modified average), so "24V" actually has a peak voltage much higher. Regardless, 29V is less than 20% over.  Anything ought to be able to handle that.  I think the service tech is shining you on.

Comment: Sounds like a crappy thermostat. Did you check the voltage under load?

Comment: The voltage is not the problem.  Look elsewhere.   Reboot the thermostat, check the wiring.

Answer (score 4):

This seems like poor design of the thermostat: most household HVAC "24 VAC" transformers are designed to provide that voltage *under load*, i.e., while drawing the design current, perhaps one ampere. Open circuit (O.C.) voltage of 29 VAC is *normal*.

That said, it would be easy to reduce the voltage to 24 VAC. Two 6 VDC zener diodes such as the [1N5340BG](https://www.mouser.com/Search/Refine?Keyword=1N5340BG) (~US$0.50 each) soldered in series, with opposite polarity, would bring the supply down to 23 VAC, giving a 1 volt margin. However, I question the manufacturer's claim that the normal O.C. voltage is causing the issue. and doubt that lowering it by 6 volts would help. More likely, the connections are incorrect or the thermostat is defective.

Answer (score 3):

I often get a 28-29 volt no load reading and have never had any issues like you're describing. They are actually designed to be 24v at 50% rated capacity so no load they should read like 24.8 or 25.1 Yes 29v is a little high it's probably a cheap transformer or a little breakdown of insulation in the secondary. Possibly high primary voltage could be adding a volt or so. Sometimes tech support spits out a pre conceived excuse for their junkie equipment. I'd say get a thermostat from a heating supplier. Home depot and the like buy cheaper versions of the stuff tradespeople get.

Answer (score 3):

The Honeywell RTH2510 is operated by batteries only. The 24V AC (or 29V AC in your case) from your HVAC equipment is simply passing through the relays in the thermostat and is not powering the thermostat. The only symptom of 29V AC being "too much" for that thermostat would be a little heat buildup after a period of the contacts being closed.

While you could have a defective thermostat, defective hvac equipment, or a bad install, it's likely (without knowing more about the symptoms) that the wiring is the problem. I would trace the wires back to the equipment and make sure the colors you're seeing there match what you expect at the thermostat.

Answer (score 0):

Transformers are rated at a given load because of the impedance of the windings. they also give a primary and secondary voltage rating. In this case the secondary rating appears to be 24 volts. The output voltage has a direct relation to the primary voltage. Secondary voltage is determined by dividing or multiplying by the turns ratio (transformers can be step up or down). 24V is a nominal rating not an exact value. There is a tolerance that is probably in the range of about plus minus three volts at a given primary voltage from full load to no load. The narrow the gap generally the better the transformer.  Also you need to consider the primary voltage rating, if it is rated at 110 and you connect it to 120 you will get more volts. If it has been running ok for a while I would not worry about it.

In this case a step down transformer you can divide the primary voltage by the secondary voltage and that will give you the turns ratio.